# SolrCloud Basic Authentication Password appears on admin page

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We set up basic authentication on solr but the credentails appear on Admin Dashboard.

Is there a way to stop particular jvm argument i.e credentials.Or can we stop all jvm arguments from appearing?

Please suggest

Comment: sorry, i didn't get your problem? you want to remove creds from admin but leave on others?

Comment: I don't want credentials to be displayed on dashboard section of solr admin..

Comment: ah, got it, cause they are right now in jvm args

Comment: Yes correct.The details are required in arg for solr to start.Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you specified login/password as plain JVM parameter, that’s why you could see it on Admin page.

However, Solr also have capability to control Basic Auth through **security.json** file which could look like this:

```
{
"authentication":{
   "blockUnknown": true,
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}
},
"authorization":{
   "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
   "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
      "role":"admin"}],
   "user-role":{"solr":"admin"}
}}
```

By doing so, we specified user  with name solr and password - which is base64 encoded string `“SolrRocks”`. This file should be properly placed either in **$SOLR_HOME** if you’re using legacy scaling or in ZooKeeper, if you’re using SolrCloud.

After doing so, you will configure Basic Auth and password won’t appear on the JVM arguments.

Of course there are general recommendations - you need to use SSL (by default password would be send in plain text), also you need to protect **securiry.json** file from modification/read as well.

For more information - check official Solr [guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/basic-authentication-plugin.html)